# Bit strange behavior of php mail function

Tags: php, email

By mistake, I added from-address as to-address in mail-function.
  It sends mail to both to-address and from-address why? Is it documented anywhere?

```
$from = 'from_user@gmail.in';
$to = 'to_user@gmail.com';

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'To: ' . $to  . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";

$message = json_encode(compact('to', 'from', 'headers'));

  // NOTE THE FROM INSTEAD OF TO
mail($from, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: I believe `To` is an additional `$headers` like `cc` or `bcc` so you are sending it to the `$from` using the `mail()` function and the `To` in the `$headers`. At least that is what I gather from the PHP Manual anyway...

Comment: See the manual: [`mail($to, $subject, $message, $additional_headers)`](http://php.net/mail). The behaviour and recognization of the envelope and second To: address depends on your smtp server.

Comment: @Rasclatt Ok, found any reference?

Comment: Yes, the PHP Manual.

Comment: @mario I couldn't see anything in the doc to understand this behavior. it tells to can have multiple users. but here i gave only one user.

Comment: @all i din't see in php doc to support this behavior.

Comment: Again, this has little to do with how PHP handles your invalid parametes, but how your SMTP server interprets or joins fields. You simply cause two `To:` fields to be present.

Comment: @mario May be the difference is that here mail function sends only one mail to from_user@gmail.com. and gmail may be sending to to_address@gmail.com. My be faster than mentioning all address in mail-function's to-address. "It is worth noting that the mail() function is not suitable for larger volumes of email in a loop. This function opens and closes an SMTP socket for each email, which is not very efficient." from php doc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further to the comments and to highlight your request for reference. Here is a snippit from the php manual for reference. Notice the first line of additional headers:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

So you are sending an email both through the `mail($to...` (which happens to be the `$from` in your case) but you are also sending the `$to` in the `$headers` declaration.

Comment: Ya, there is example but didn't explain it anywhere ;)